# Spark Pivot On Date

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, dataframe, pivot

The original DataFrame looks like:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|             user_id|    measurement_date|            features|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|b6d0bb3d-7a8e-4ac...|2016-06-28 02:00:...|[3492.68576170840...|
..
|048ffee9-a942-4d1...|2016-04-28 02:00:...|[1404.42230898422...|
|05101595-5a6f-4cd...|2016-07-10 02:00:...|[1898.50082132108...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

My pivoting efforts:

```
data = data.select(data.col("user_id"),data.col("features"),data.col("measurement_date").cast(DateType).alias("date")).filter(data.col("measurement_date").between("2016-01-01", "2016-01-07"))
data = data.select(data.col("user_id"),data.col("features"),data.col("date")).groupBy("user_id","features").pivot("date").min()
```

I the output is:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             user_id|            features|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|14cd26dc-200a-436...|[2281.34579074947...|
..
|d8ae1b5e-c1e0-4bf...|[2568.49641198251...|
|1cceb175-12b4-4c3...|[4436.36029554227...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The columns I want 2016-01-01,..,2016-01-07 are missing, nothing was pivoted at all.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is how the DataFrame looks after the first statement:

```
|             user_id|            features|      date|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|60f1cd63-0d5a-4f2...|[1553.35305181118...|2016-01-05|
|a56d1fef-5f17-4c9...|[1704.34897309186...|2016-01-02|
..
|992b6a34-803d-44b...|[1518.14292508305...|2016-01-05|
```

It might be noteworthy that (user_id, features) is not a time series, there are gaps in the data. Sometimes there are no measurements for certain dates, in that case I want Null as entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the aggregation part. So that your second line of code should be

```
data = data.select(data.col("user_id"),data.col("features"),data.col("date")).groupBy("user_id","features").pivot("date").agg(min("date"))
```

Comment: .min() already is a aggregation function. It should give the same result as .agg(min("date")). Other than that strangely I get the error "can not resolve symbol agg" when I try your approach.

Comment: Never mind, agg works. It was the combination with min("date") that did not resolve.

Comment: I had to import "import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._" for your code to work. I was wrong with my assumption. They are not equivalent.

Comment: Ramesh, thanks for the awnser. The final solution is:
"data = data.select(data.col("user_id"),data.col("features"),data.col("date")).groupBy("user_id","features").pivot("date").agg(min("features"))"

Comment: great to hear that @user4054919. and thanks for the upvote and acceptance :)